# Need variable number of drop-down lists in a gridview template field

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have the following gridview defined which is populating perfectly:

```
    <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="chargeDetail" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="LineItemNumber,DetailId,IsParking" CellSpacing="0" CellPadding="6"
     HorizontalAlign="Center" EnableViewState="true" ShowFooter="true">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentID" HeaderText="Student ID" ReadOnly="True" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="StudentName" HeaderText="Name" ReadOnly="true" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CampusName" HeaderText="Campus" ReadOnly="true" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="LineItemDetailLabel" Text='<%# IIf(Eval("Mandatory") = "1", Eval("LineItemDetail") + " *", Eval("LineItemDetail")) %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Cost" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    $<asp:Label runat="server" ID="LineItemCostLabel" Text='<%# Eval("LineItemCost") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Options" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblOptionsAvailable" 
                     Text='<%# IIf(Eval("AttributesAvailable") = "1", "Options will be available to select on the next screen.", "No options available.") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Pay Now" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" FooterText="Total:">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Checkbox runat="server" ID="cbLineItemSelected" Checked='<%# IIf(Eval("Selected") = "1", "True", "False") %>'
                     Enabled='<%# IIf(Eval("Mandatory") = "1", "False", "True") %>' AutoPostBack="True" OnCheckedChanged="cbLineItemSelected_CheckedChanged" />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterStyle Font-Bold="True" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    $<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblLineTotalCost" Text='<%# IIf(Eval("Selected") = "1", Eval("LineItemCost"), "0.00") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <FooterTemplate>
                    $<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblTotal" />
                </FooterTemplate>
                <FooterStyle Font-Bold="True" />
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

In the TemplateField where HeaderText="Options", I need to be able to create a variable number of drop-down lists. For each fee the school may be charging, they could have any number of attributes associated. For example, a TShirt fee may need to collect Size and Color and each attribute may have multiple options.

Right now, you can see I have a label that is populating correctly but I need to be able to create the two drop-down lists, in this case for Size and Color, so the parent can specify them when they check the box to include this fee in their charges. You'll notice that in the Pay Now column, the checkbox has an OnCheckedChanged event which currently updates the total column and overall total in the footer row.

I would ideally like that event to populate the drop-downs when it is checked so the parent can make their selections. I'll also need to know how to handle the post back from those drop-downs so I can get the selections recorded correctly.

From what I can find, I'm guessing I need to create a nested gridview where I can put the drop-downlists but I can't find any examples to point me in the right direction of how to make that work. I can easily populate the drop-downs from the code behind and if pointed in the right direction, access the data as the parents enter it. Just need a bit of direction or an easier way.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: OK, I added a gridview inside the ItemTemplate. Codebehind: `Protected Sub chargeDetail_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles chargeDetail.RowDataBound
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
            Dim gv As GridView = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("gvOptions"), GridView)
            gv.DataSource = GetOptions(chargeDetail.DataKeys(e.Row.RowIndex).Values("DetailId"))
            gv.DataBind()
        End If
    End Sub`. Works so far but now I need to know how to address the DDLs in the nested gridview.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I came up with a solution that seems to work. Inside the gridview definition, I nested another gridview with the drop-down list inside of it as follows:

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Options" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gvOptions" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="AttributeId" HorizontalAlign="center" EnableViewState="true"
                    GridLines="None" EmptyDataText="No available options." ShowHeader="False">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" ReadOnly="true" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlOptionSelection" DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="OptionId"
                                    EnableViewState="true" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlOptionSelection_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

The challenge was figuring out how to tie everything together since data in the nested gridview relied on data keys from the parent gridview. The RowDataBound event for the parent finds the child gridview and populates the dropdowns as follows (gvOptions is the child and chargeDetail is the parent):

```
Protected Sub chargeDetail_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles chargeDetail.RowDataBound
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        Dim gv As GridView = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("gvOptions"), GridView)
        Dim cb As CheckBox = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("cbLineItemSelected"), CheckBox)
        Dim lineItem As String = chargeDetail.DataKeys(e.Row.RowIndex).Values("LineItemNumber")
        gv.DataSource = GetOptions(chargeDetail.DataKeys(e.Row.RowIndex).Values("DetailId"))
        gv.DataBind()

        Dim gridLineCount As Integer = gv.Rows.Count()
        Dim gridWorkingRow As Integer

        For gridWorkingRow = 0 To gridLineCount - 1
            Dim ddl As DropDownList = gv.Rows(gridWorkingRow).FindControl("ddlOptionSelection")
            Dim AttribId As Integer = gv.DataKeys(gridWorkingRow).Values("AttributeId")
            ddl.DataSource = PopulateOptions(AttribId)
            ddl.DataBind()
            ddl.SelectedValue = GetSelectedValue(AttribId, lineItem)

            If cb.Checked Then
                ddl.Enabled = True
            Else
                ddl.Enabled = False
            End If
        Next gridWorkingRow
    End If
End Sub
```

When one of the dropdowns change, the following is fired. I found it easier, based on how the data is stored in the database, to re-send all of the options since the attribute:option pairs are concatenated to be stored in a single field:

```
Protected Sub ddlOptionSelection_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim ddlSender As DropDownList = DirectCast(sender, DropDownList)
    Dim row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(ddlSender.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
    Dim gvOption As GridView = DirectCast(row.NamingContainer, GridView)
    Dim chargeDetailRow As GridViewRow = DirectCast(gvOption.Parent.Parent, GridViewRow)
    Dim LineItemNumber As Integer = CInt(chargeDetail.DataKeys(chargeDetailRow.RowIndex).Values("LineItemNumber"))

    Dim gridLineCount As Integer = gvOption.Rows.Count()
    Dim gridWorkingRow As Integer
    Dim OptionString As String = ""

    For gridWorkingRow = 0 To gridLineCount - 1
        Dim ddl As DropDownList = gvOption.Rows(gridWorkingRow).FindControl("ddlOptionSelection")
        Dim AttribId As String = gvOption.DataKeys(gridWorkingRow).Values("AttributeId")

        If gridWorkingRow = gridLineCount - 1 Then
            OptionString = OptionString + AttribId + ":" + ddl.SelectedValue
        Else
            OptionString = OptionString + AttribId + ":" + ddl.SelectedValue + ","
        End If
    Next gridWorkingRow

    Dim PortalConn As New SqlConnection
    PortalConn.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("PortalConnStr").ConnectionString
    PortalConn.Open()

    Dim WriteBackSQL As New SqlCommand("sp_schedulePickup_UpdateOption", PortalConn)
    WriteBackSQL.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
    WriteBackSQL.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@SessionID", Session.SessionID.ToString()))
    WriteBackSQL.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@LineItemNumber", LineItemNumber))
    WriteBackSQL.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Option", OptionString))

    Dim returnStatus As Integer
    Dim rsReturn As SqlDataReader = WriteBackSQL.ExecuteReader()
    Do While rsReturn.Read()
        returnStatus = rsReturn("ReturnStatus")
    Loop
    rsReturn.Close()
    rsReturn = Nothing

    PortalConn.Close()
    PortalConn = Nothing

    chargeDetail.DataSource = GetChargeDetails()
    chargeDetail.DataBind()
    getTotal()
End Sub
```